# How do make a list in which the subelements are joined in (Python Element tree)

Tags: python, list, elementtree

I have this sample XML code

```
<pathway>
    <relation entry1="62" entry2="64" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    </relation>
    <relation entry1="54" entry2="55" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
        <subtype name="phosphorylation" value="+p"/>
    </relation>
    <relation entry1="55" entry2="82" type="PPrel">
        <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
        <subtype name="phosphorylation" value="+p"/>
    </relation>
</pathway>
```

I'm trying to sort the subtypes into a list, but if the entry has multiple subtypes, to combine them into one string

Example output: 
['activation', 'activation; phosphorylation', 'activation; phosphorylation']

My current code is

```
tree= ET.parse('file.xml')
root= tree.getroot()
relation = []
for son in root:
    for step_son in son:
        if len(son.getchildren()) > 1:
            relation.append(step_son.get('name'))
        if len(son.getchildren()) < 2:
            relation.append(step_son.get('name'))
```

and my output for relation is:

['activation', 'activation', 'phosphorylation', 'activation', phosphorylation']

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find and iterating each matching element:

```
In [35]: from xml.etree import ElementTree
In [36]: xml_string = """
    ...: <pathway>
    ...:     <relation entry1="62" entry2="64" type="PPrel">
    ...:         <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    ...:     </relation>
    ...:     <relation entry1="54" entry2="55" type="PPrel">
    ...:         <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    ...:         <subtype name="phosphorylation" value="+p"/>
    ...:     </relation>
    ...:     <relation entry1="55" entry2="82" type="PPrel">
    ...:         <subtype name="activation" value="--&gt;"/>
    ...:         <subtype name="phosphorylation" value="+p"/>
    ...:     </relation>
    ...: </pathway>"""

In [37]: p_element = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)

In [38]: result = []

In [39]: for relation in p_element.findall('.//relation'):
    ...:    result.append(';'.join(x.attrib['name'] for x in relation.findall('.//subtype')))
    ...:

In [40]: result
Out[40]: ['activation', 'activation;phosphorylation', 'activation;phosphorylation']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.